# x.objects.all() empty, user.x_set.all() not empty

Tags: python, django

This is probably really simple but I don't think I've come across this problem before.

I have an object in my database called WeatherForecast, this object has a foreign key to User, so the user can have a number of different forecasts displayed in a template.

```
class WeatherForecast(models.Model):


    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
```

I create the forecasts and set the foreign key as such:

```
newForecast = WeatherForecast.objects.create(owner = request.user)
```

When I call `WeatherForecast.objects.all()`, it returns an empty query set. However, when I call `user.weatherforecast_set.all()` it returns the WeatherForecasts with the correct foreign key.

I'm probably missing something obvious, but why is this happening?

EDIT:

Here is where I am calling it.

Originally, I was doing this to get a number of selected forecasts (selections were made from the template via a form, the IDs were taken from the form and put into a list and I have verified that the IDs are being passed from the form correctly).

```
for weatherForecastID in selectedIDs:

selectedForecast = WeatherForecast.objects.get(id = weatherForecastID)
```

I was getting `WeatherForecast matching this query does not exist` errors from that. After looking into it, I found the issue I am having, where the `objects.all()` is empty but the `weatherforecast_set.all()` isn't.

To make sure I wasn't missing something silly, I also printed the query sets like so:

```
print "all weather forecasts:", WeatherForecast.objects.all()
print "user weather forecasts:", request.user.weatherforecast_set.all()
```

which gives:

```
all weather forecasts: <QuerySet []>
user weather forecasts: <QuerySet [<WeatherForecast: WeatherForecast object>]>
```

EDIT 2

FIXED! There was a model in a different app with the same name, causing the query to be looking in the wrong table! Feel like a bit of an idiot now!

Thank you everyone for the help!

Comment: What you say is impossible. You are probably doing something else that you don't show us here.

Comment: Did you change model manager on `WeatherForecast`?

Comment: thanks for getting back to me!
no, I haven't changed anything to do with the model manager

Comment: can you show code where you call it?

Comment: 1. Can you show the exact output on both call i.e. WeatherForecast.objects.all() and user.weatherforecast_set.all()
2. Can you also goto database and hit the sql "select count(*) from {{app_name}}_weatherforecast and show us here?

Comment: How are you determining its empty? Do you have a breakpoint set? have you stepped over it?

Comment: That's not really possible if you haven't changed anything.